# Span of Polynomials in $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{P}=\{1, x, x^2, x^3 \ldots\}$. Then pick out the correct statements.

A) Span$\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$

B) Span$\mathcal{P}$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$

C) $\{1, x, x^2, x^3 \ldots\}$ is a linearly independent set.

D) Trigonometric functions belong to Span$\mathcal{P}$.

C is obviously correct. The thing is need clarification is this. Is there a difference between $Span\mathcal{P}$ and closure of $Span\mathcal{P}$. So my answer is **only B and C are correct** Is that alright?

Comment: There are situations where one is only interested in closed subspaces of a topological vector space, and then it can make sense to let $\operatorname{span} S$ denote the closure of the linear span of $S$. But if such a convention is used, it ought to be explicitly introduced, since the standard usage is different. Thus I'm relatively sure that your answer is all right.

Comment: Its fairly common to use $\overline{\rm span} S$ or $\overline{\rm lin} S$ for the closed linear span of a subset $S$ in a topological vector space.

Comment: See also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334796/operatornamespanx0-x1-x2-cdots-and-the-vector-space-of-all-real-val