# $\operatorname{span}(x^0, x^1, x^2,\cdots)$ and the vector space of all real valued continuous functions on $\Bbb R$

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

> Let $p_n(x)=x^n$ for $x\in\Bbb R$ and let $\mathcal P=span\{p_0,p_1,p_2,\cdots\}$ . Then
>
> 1. $\mathcal P$ is the vector space of all real valued continuous functions on $\Bbb R$.
> 2. $\mathcal P$ is the subspace of all real valued continuous functions on $\Bbb R$.
> 3. $\{p_0,p_1,p_2,\cdots\}$ is a linearly independent set in the vector space of all continuous functions on $\Bbb R$.
> 4. Trigonometric functions belong to $\mathcal P$

Not 1 since sinc function is real valued and continuous, and not 4, too. Can I conclude 2,3 are the correct ones?

Comment: You may find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334687/span-of-polynomials-in-mathcalc-mathbbr#comment2712218_1334687) interesting (same question), especially the comment section. bests

Comment: 2. is not correct because there isn't *one* subspace of all real valued functions, there a many. So $\mathcal{P}$ is *a* subspace, but its not *the* subspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly. 
4. doesn't hold in general, so neither does 1. 
2. and 3. are true, $\mathcal P$ is *a* subspace of the space of all continuous functions, and the polynomials $p_n$ are linearly independent from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Exponential function are real and cnts.
Doesn't belongs to v
So 1 is incorrect
Sinx is cont. But Doesn't belongs to v
So v is subspace also set of polynomial is independent
So 2 and 4th is correct