# Is there any trigonometric function that cannot be written as an infinite series?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometric-series

Let $p_n(x)=x^n$ for $x\in \Bbb{R}$ and  let  P=span$\{p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3\dots\}$. Then-

1. P  is  the  vector space  of  all   real  valued continuous  functions  on R
2. P  is a  subspace  of  all  real  valued  continuous  functions  on  R.
3. The  set $\{p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3\dots\}$  is  linearly  independent  in  the vector  space  of  all  continuous functions  on  R
4. Trigonometric  functions  belong  to  P

I  can  easily  see option  1.  is  false  and  option 2.  and  3.  are  correct but I  am  not  sure  about  option 4.

Why  would any  trigonometric  function not belong P= span $\{p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3\dots\}$

Comment: You might be interested in the concept of a Laurent decomposition. The idea is that certain functions (for example $\frac{1}{x}$) are not equal to their own taylor series (they are no 'analytic'). The trick of the Laurent decomposition is that besides positive powers of $x$, also negative powers of $x$ are allowed. Using this method of expansion every function on $\mathbb{R}$ has a laurent decomposition around every point in it's domain. There might be different compositions around different points though.

Comment: Same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334796/operatornamespanx0-x1-x2-cdots-and-the-vector-space-of-all-real-val and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334687/span-of-polynomials-in-mathcalc-mathbbr#comment2712218_1334687, although the answers there don't fully explain your question about (4)

Comment: Linear combination (and everything that follows, like: span, linear dependence etc.) is defined as a ***finite*** sum, because it's a purely algebraic concept. We can deal with infinte sums like power series, but we need additional mathematical structures and terms (mostly ones form mathematical analysis like convergence). That's why we don't say that "P spans the set of all analytical functions on $\mathbb{R}$", but rather that it forms a complete (dense) subset of the bigger space.

Answer (score 2):

Your $P $ does not contain any infinite series. The span is the set of linear combinations of the $p_n $; in fact whoever wrote the question called it $P $ because it is the set of *polynomials*.

So the question is whether any trigonometric function is a polynomial. The answer is no, because a polynomial cannot be periodic.

Comment: That's  the  point  I missed. Any  element  of  the  span  would take  only finitely many  elements  of  P with  non-zero  coefficient . So, no  series.

Comment: @Martin Argerami the given span contains infinite members, and a polynomial can be expressed with only finite number of members from that span. Whatever it is, but it isn't indicating towards polynomial. And one thing, trigonometric function can be in that span , for example, $sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdot\cdot\cdot $ , and there are some trigonometric function which are not belonging into that span like $sin(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: @Alearner: no. $ $

Comment: @Martin Argerami : Why no??

Comment: Because of what *span* means.

Comment: @Martin Argerami : can you give something on about this, as the spanning set contains infinite members, why a Tylor series expansion can't be in that spanned space, please, I am very curious about it!

Comment: The span of a set is the set of all linear combinations of the elements. A linear combination is formed by taking a finite number of elements, a coefficient for each element, and then form the sum "coefficient times element". This may not clarify things depending on your mathematical maturity, but to talk about series you need to talk about limits; to talk about limits you need to have a topology, i.e. a notion of what it means to be near. In a vector space you don't have those things a priori; an infinite sum makes no sense in a vector space unless you consider additional structure.

Answer (score 1):

Some functions cannot be written as Taylor series because they have a singularity for example $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-\cos z}$.

Comment: @Mitsos yeah but that is not in P